# Running multiple emacs versions with homebrew

Tags: emacs24

Perhaps this is more of a homebrew question, but I imagine someone here knows the answer. What is the best way to have two versions of emacs on OS X with homebrew? I need to be able to quickly switch between emacs 24 and 25 in order to properly test some packages I maintain, but it seems that switching between the two forces a full rebuild of emacs.

I figure I must be doing something wrong. So, what's the proper way to have two versions that I can quickly switch between? Is there some homebrew incantation that lets me unlink/link versions that are already built?

Comment: Why do you think that you did something wrong?  Sometimes a piece of software simply doesn't support your use case…

Comment: I guess my point is that this seems like a common enough thing that I assumed it was supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homebrew doesn't let you install multiple versions side-by-side.  You can however use the binaries from [Emacs for Mac OS X](http://emacsformacosx.com/builds) to quickly switch between different Emacs versions.  I frequently use these builds to debug problems on older Emacs versions, or to bisect issues on Emacs 25.